# Determine limit of telescoping series

Tags: calculus

[image]

Suppose: $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$

The answer should be in the form of $f(a)$

So I've written $f(x + y) = f(\frac{1}{k + 1}) + f(\frac{-1}{k - 1})$

Then I wrote a couple of sequences and saw that terms cancel each other out and I get $f(1) + f(\frac{1}{2}) - f(\frac{1}{N}) - f(\frac{1}{N + 1})$

which with N approaching infinity gives me $f(1) + f(\frac{1}{2}) + f(0) + f(0)$

and since the statement about $f$ , I get the answer as  $f(\frac{3}{2})$

Is this the right way to approach this?

Comment: That looks like the right way to approach the question, assuming that $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$ holds. Also notice, one of your partial fractions should have $k-1$ in the denominator.

Comment: @Joppy Oh yeah that's right

Comment: Are you aware that the only functions that verify $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$ are the linear functions $f(x)=ax$ ? Thus your issue become much simpler ... it becomes the convergence of the series $2a \sum {1}{k^2-1}$.

Comment: @JeanMarie That's not true unless continuity of $f$ is assumed. But the OP also uses continuity when taking the limit of $f \left( \frac{1}{N} \right)$, so maybe it's meant to assume it?

Comment: @Adayah You are right. This( Cauchy) result assumes continuity, and I had done it implicitly, forgetting to mention it explicitly.

Comment: Not sure I follow, I've been given the first two statements so I assumed this was the best way to get $f(a)$

Comment: sorry : read in my previous answer : "convergence of $2a \sum \dfrac{1}{k^2-1}$'

Comment: @JeanMarie I was supposed to use the result from the previous exercise which was to solve the limit of the same series without the $f()$ which ended up giving me the limit as $\frac{3}{2}$, so I thought I should solve it in the same way. I don't see how I can get a definitive answer for that series, all I see is that it approaches 1

Answer (score 0):

You solution is correct, but there is one thing left to justify: why does

$$\lim_{N \to \infty} f \left( \frac{1}{N} \right) = 0 \ ?$$

Comment: isn't it $ = f(0)$?

Comment: @JohnDoe It is, but why?

Comment: I know why but I don't know how to prove it

Comment: @JohnDoe Hint: prove that $f \left( \frac{1}{N} \right) = \frac{1}{N} f(1)$.

Comment: could I say that because $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ then the function has to be linear which also means that it is homogenous?

Comment: @JohnDoe A function such that $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$ does not have to be linear. It has to be linear over $\mathbb{Q}$, i.e. $f(\alpha \cdot x) = \alpha \cdot f(x)$ for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}$. But proving $f \left( \frac{1}{N} \right) = \frac{1}{N} f(1)$ is a special case of it, which is better done directly.